# Header information lost when calling a specific ColdFusion file

Tags: coldfusion

We are experiencing an elusive and frustrating issue as we attempt to migrate an internal ColdFusion website to a new server. The new server is Windows NT 6.0 with IIS 7, running ColdFusion 11.

Siteminder sends information via the header, including what RACF groups the user is in. The ColdFusion application.cfm file then sets this list as a variable, and the page checks against it to determine what area(s) the user works in and display the correct menu options, etc.

However, whenever the file name is typed out, it does not receive the header information. For example, with index.cfm set as the default page:

WorkforceTracking.localnet.com/Jobs/ - returns RACF group header.
WorkforceTracking.localnet.com/Jobs/index.cfm - does NOT return RACF group header.

We initially suspected that Siteminder was not set up to protect the sub-sites correctly. We were provided a file by our Siteminder team to check if the header information is coming through for other files in the directory, and it is. For the root site, and for any non-.cfm file, the header information comes through correctly.

This is true no matter what we set the default site to - I have changed it to other .cfm files, and they will receive the header information.

So, this seems to indicate that ColdFusion itself is losing the header information when a file is called directly. I am new to the server admin role, and am not sure what steps to take from here. Does anyone know why ColdFusion would be losing header information when a specific .cfm file is called?

Edit - 
Currently, I have stripped down the application.cfm and index files to just output the header information, and have the index page say "Hello." The index.cfm file is below:

```
<cfset x = GetHttpRequestData()> 
<cfoutput> 
<table cellpadding = "2" cellspacing = "2"> 
<tr> 
    <td><b>HTTP Request item</b></td> 
    <td><b>Value</b></td> 
</tr> 
<cfloop collection = #x.headers# item = "http_item"> 
    <tr> 
        <td>#http_item#</td> 
        <td>#StructFind(x.headers, http_item)#</td>
    </tr> 
</cfloop> 
<tr> 
    <td>request_method</td> 
    <td>#x.method#</td>
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>server_protocol</td> 
    <td>#x.protocol#</td>
</tr> 
</table> 
<b>http_content --- #x.content#</b> 
</cfoutput>

<cfoutput>Hello!</cfoutput>
```

And (some) of the header output:

**For devworkforcetracking2.localnet.com/Jobs/** 
content-length  0 
JDWAS_RACFGROUPS    U90^$IMS10G^$IMS20G^$IMS21G^$IMS30G^$TSO11^$TSO12^  (etc.) 
SM_AUTHREASON   0

**For devworkforcetracking2.localnet.com/Jobs/index.cfm** 
content-length  0  
SM_SERVERSESSIONID  a9CkEe5LwWPXXPu9a4Mssy8+o3w= (appears earlier for /Jobs/)  
SM_AUTHREASON   0

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: I don't believe that ColdFusion is _losing the header information_. Most likely it is not being passed in the specific scenario you mention. What web server and JEE server are you running for the site? My guess is that it has something to do with the connector and/or any redirect rules configured on the web server.

Comment: cfquery, Miguel - thanks for the response. I updated the post to answer both questions.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to enable trace on the SiteMinder webagent and see the details printed for the *WorkforceTracking.localnet.com/Jobs/index.cfm* resource.

If the headers are being passed, they would be getting printed in the siteminder agent trace log file.

Comment: Ultimately, when we viewed the header information being passed, we saw that the headers were NOT being included when the specific file was called. However, this did not help us figure out why. 

We eventually were forced to find an alternate solution. Thank you for the response.

Comment: OK.. Great that you found an alternate solution.  However the only reason headers wouldn't be passed is that that siteminder rule/event that the headers are tagged to is not being fired/generated.  If you run into the problem again.. You should look at the trace log and see if the event was generated in

Comment: Agreed. However, we believe that it was firing, as we were receiving some (but not all!) of the Siteminder data. 

We looked through every log we could, and asked our Siteminder team for assistance. As far as anyone could tell, it should have worked. It just didn't.